# How to remove an element from JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have Object Name `Roption` and I want to remove third element inside Add Task.

This one => `"{ text: "Child",  alias: "addsubbelowchild", action:menuAction}"`

I am using **Delete Roption.items[0].items[2]**.

It works but  Roption.items[0].items.length returns the same count number even after deleting.

Is it really deleting or just making it undefined?

```
 var Roption = { width: 150, items: [
                { text: "Add Task",  alias: "addtask", type: "group" , width : 130 , items : 
                    [   
                        { text: "Sibling",  alias: "addsiblingbelow", action : menuAction},
                        { text: "Child First", alias: "addsubaboveDirect", action: menuAction },
                        { text: "Child Last",  alias: "addsubbelowDirect", action: menuAction },
                        { text: "Child",  alias: "addsubbelowchild", action:menuAction},
                        { text: "Advanced Add",  alias: "advancedadd", type: "group" , width : 120 , items :
                            [
                                { text: "Sibling", alias: "addsibling", type: "group" , width : 120 ,items :
                                    [
                                        { text: "Below",  alias: "addsiblingbelow", action: menuAction },
                                        { text: "Above",  alias: "addsiblingabove", action: menuAction }
                                    ]
                                },
                                { text: "Child", alias: "addsubtask", type: "group" , width : 120 ,items :
                                    [
                                        { text: "First", alias: "addsubabove", action: menuAction },
                                        { text: "Last", alias: "addsubbelow", action: menuAction }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
                , onShow: applyrule
                , onContextMenu: BeforeContextMenu
                , onClose : AfterContextMenu
};
function menuAction(row) {}
function BeforeContextMenu(row) {}
function applyrule(row) {}
function AfterContextMenu(row) {}
```

Comment: if you want to delete array item, you may use `splice` method

Comment: @Anton delete returns True...

Comment: @IgorDymov  Actually it works.. but splices works on array prototype... and its object.. Correct me if I am wrong!! –

Comment: items is an array right? and i wrote wrong, it doesn't return null but it returns undefined like this [1, 2, undefined × 1, 4]

Comment: @RiteshChandora `Roption` is an object, and `items` are arrays in both cases

Comment: @Anton but Push or Pop Operation can not be performed on items..
Why????

Comment: Roption.items[0].items.push({"test":"testing"}); try this and you'll see it works @RiteshChandora

Comment: @IgorDymov  but Push or Pop Operation can not be performed on items.. Why???? It gives error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.splice(index,howmany)`

```
Roption.items[0].items.splice(2,1);
```

Comment: Actually it works.. but splices works on array prototype... and its object..
Correct me if I am wrong!!

Comment: Items is an array with objects inside the array @RiteshChandora